# Command Line Remove Hidden (Unplugged) Device

Tags: windows-8, command-line, device-manager

Good morning,

I am attempting to remove an unplugged/phantom device via the command line. I have tried Microsoft's DevCon.exe `devcon remove "HWID"` but it is not able to remove it returning `No devices removed.`

I am able to see the device I want to remove by running `set devmgr_show_nonpresent_devices=1`, however, devcon.exe is still not able to remove it. Also, by right clicking the hidden device in devmgmt.msc and selecting remove, I am able to remove it, but I need to remove this exact device from >1000 machines so manually doing it is not feasible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. There is an awesome utility called GhostBuster which has command line functionality in the latest version. Seen here:

https://ghostbuster.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced%20Options&referringTitle=Documentation

Worked perfectly!